# adding groups for same css code

Tags: html, css

I have a lot of same css code applying to different html elements

e.g. the following code is written about 100 times

```
display: -webkit-box;
display: -moz-box;
display: -ms-flexbox;
display: -webkit-flex;
display: flex;
```

Is it possible to create like a class and the just add this class to the html element, so it's every time only one line and not 5 rows.

Comma separated isn't possible there are to much elements.

I searched Google but din't find anything which matches my problem.

Thank you for your answer :)

Comment: Well, that's what LESS and SASS does (one of many things).

Comment: You might want to look at a preprocessing language, like SCSS/LESS. A mixin is what you're looking for.

Comment: What selector are you using? Not a class?

Comment: SCSS is looking like a nice solution, thx :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first option I'm about to post was already posted and removed for some reason. Don't know why, it was completely valid.

You can create a class to apply to all affected elements:

```css
.flex {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex"></div>
<div></div>
<div class="flex"></div>
```

Or you can use a CSS preprocessor like [LESS](http://lesscss.org/#). You can do it a couple ways with LESS. First, [extend](http://lesscss.org/features/#extend-feature):

```less
.flex {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
}
.selector-1 {
    &:extend( .flex );
    /* custom styles here */
}
.selector-2 {
    &:extend( .flex );
    /* custom styles here */
}
.selector-3 {
    &:extend( .flex );
    /* custom styles here */
}
```

Above outputs:

```css
.flex,
.selector-1,
.selector-2,
.selector-3 {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
}
.selector-1 {
    /* custom styles here */
}
.selector-2 {
    /* custom styles here */
}
.selector-3 {
    /* custom styles here */
}
```

Or you can use a [mix-in](http://lesscss.org/features/#mixins-feature):

```less
.flex() {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
}
.selector-1 {
    .flex;
    /* custom styles here */
}
.selector-2 {
    .flex;
    /* custom styles here */
}
.selector-3 {
    .flex;
    /* custom styles here */
}
```

Above outputs:

```css
.selector-1 {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    /* custom styles here */
}
.selector-2 {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    /* custom styles here */
}
.selector-3 {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    /* custom styles here */
}
```